# Containerized nginx server return 503 error

Tags: django, docker, nginx, deployment, docker-compose

I am trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy for running multiple web apps. My files' contents are as below:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV APP_ROOT /mysite/subdomain.mysite
ENV PROD True

ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt
ADD Pipfile /Pipfile
ADD Pipfile.lock /Pipfile.lock

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}
COPY mime.types /etc/mime.types

EXPOSE 8001

RUN if [ -f manage.py ]; then python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; fi

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8001", "subdomain.wsgi"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  postgres:
    container_name:  subdomain-postgres
    image:           postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    # .env file contains postgres username, database name and password
    env_file: .env

  webapp:
    container_name: subdomain
    build: .
    restart: "always"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=subdomain.mysite.com,www.subdomain.mysite.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8001
      - TIMEOUT=300
      - HTTP_PORT=8001
      - STATS_PORT=8046
    volumes: 
      - .:/subdomain.mysite
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

As you see from above files I am running services `postgres` and `webapp` that are built on `python` image. My web app is a django project and `.env` file referenced in above docker files just contain postgresql related variables (username, database name, password and etc.). As of `nginx-proxy` network, it is a custom network created by me for running web and postgres services. You can refer to below files for mentioned network's configuration:

nginx-proxy/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./subdomain.mysite.com:/etc/nginx/vhost.d/subdomain.mysite.com
      - /home/elgin/mysite/subdomain.mysite:/var/data

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

nginx-proxy/nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    client_max_body_size 200M;
}
```

With the above files located on virtual server, my problem is that nginx returns `503` error. When I go to "mysite.com", it says "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" and on "subdomain.mysite.com" it says "that address is not found". 
I start mentioned services (nginx-proxy, webapp and postgres) firstly by running `docker netwrok create nginx-proxy` and then running `docker-compose up --build -d` firstly for nginx and then my web app. Nginx logs are as below (got by running `docker logs nginx-proxy`):

```
WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:01 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 1 containers
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:01 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:01 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:01 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
2019/08/15 18:20:03 [notice] 43#43: signal process started
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
dhparam generation complete, reloading nginx
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:33 Received event start for container f5d3bb924258
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:33 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:34 Received event die for container f5d3bb924258
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:34 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:36 Received event start for container 0bef2e2afdec
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:36 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:37 Received event start for container cc8a78a23572
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:37 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 3 containers
dockergen.1 | 2019/08/15 18:20:37 Running 'nginx -s reload'
```

I can't understand what am I doing wrong? Please help me for unraveling the issue behind my codes.

EDIT:

See below nginx conf file for subdomain.mysite.com:

```
location /static {
    root /var/data;
}
```

Comment: can you add nginx conf of    subdomain.mysite.com ?

Comment: problem can be connected with not absolute path in volumes. When it is not absolute => docker create such volume (not map data from disc with this not absolute path)

Comment: I have added contents of nginx conf of subdomain.mysite.com.